# Binding lsmod module name with kernel configuration menu entry

Tags: search, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

Lets suppose I have a module named "mptsas". How can I find out, what kernel configuration menu entry (make menuconfig inside /usr/src/linux) corresponds to that module?

By 'corresponds' I mean what menu entry compiles the appropriate module into the kernel.

[image]

//edit: it works very nicely:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no recorded association. You need to explore the makefiles in the kernel source. You'll find lines like

```
obj-$(CONFIG_FUSION_SAS)        += mptbase.o mptscsih.o mptsas.o
```

This means that:

- If `CONFIG_FUSION_SAS` is `y`, then the drivers `mptbase`, `mptscsih` and `mptsas` are compiled into the kernel.
- If `CONFIG_FUSION_SAS` is `m`, then the drivers `mptbase`, `mptscsih` and `mptsas` are compiled as modules.
- If `CONFIG_FUSION_SAS` is `n`, then the drivers `mptbase`, `mptscsih` and `mptsas` are not compiled.

The command `grep -R --include=Makefile '\bNAME\.o\b'` from the top of the kernel source tree will return the relevant makefile line in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Be warned that the `lsmod` command lists *module's name*, not the module's *filename*. They may be different. For instance the `aesni_intel` module is located in a module file `aesni-intel` (hyphen, not underscore); therefore you must search for `aesni-intel` in order to find the corresponding kernel configuration tag entry:

```shellsession
$ grep -R --include=Makefile '\baesni-intel\.o\b'
arch/x86/crypto/Makefile:obj-$(CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL) += aesni-intel.o
```

EDIT:
In this circumstance it may be useful the `modinfo` command that it shows the module's *filename*:

```shellsession
# modinfo aesni_intel | grep filename
filename:       /lib/modules/5.10.162/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/aesni-intel.ko
```